# StackExchange.Redis.IDatabase exists in two dlls

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redis

I installed Redis StackExchange nuget and things worked fine. But then I installed RedisSessionStateProvider nuget, which installed StackExchange.Redis.StrongName along with it.

Now I am getting the following error,

> Error 107 The type 'StackExchange.Redis.IDatabase' exists in both
>   'e:\Source\packages\StackExchange.Redis.1.0.481\lib\net45\StackExchange.Redis.dll'
>   and
>   'e:\Source\packages\StackExchange.Redis.StrongName.1.0.481\lib\net45\StackExchange.Redis.StrongName.dll'  E:\Source\MyApp\Helpers\RedisHelper\StackExchangeRedisExtensions.cs 13  37  MyApp

Why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some methods/properties/interfaces are `duplicated` in above 2 dlls.

Remove StackExchange.Redis reference to resolve errors.

Answer (score 10):

There's a lot of confusion between the strong-named dll and the non-strong-named dll namespaces.

You can easily solve this by using `extern alias`.

1. Right click on project references and pick the dll you want to refer, go to properties window. Then, change the `Aliases` field value to anything you want. E.g: "Redis".
2. Then go to your consumer source-file and add:

   ```
   extern alias Redis;

   using System;
   // ... other references
   using Redis::StackExchange.Redis;

   namespace Foo
   {
       public class Program
       {
           public static void Main(string[] args)
           {
               using (ConnectionMultiplexer connection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("myConn"))
               {
                   // use StackExchange API here.
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

There's also an [issue on StackExchange's repository](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/146) explaining more about StrongName vs Non-StrongName.

Comment: I can't seem to find that "Aliases" field you're talking about. Can you please be more detailed?

Comment: I just changed the Alias for StackExchange.Redis.StrongName from "global" to "RedisStrongName", rebuilt the solution and there were no errors

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue in an ASP.NET Core app, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46047718/stackexchange-redis-strongname-is-refrenced-but-not-included-as-package/46067860#46067860) answer solved my issue quickly.

Comment: Link-only answer is discouraged on SO.

Comment: Did you check the link before downvoting? It's a SO answer.

Comment: In which case, isn't this a dupe?... or a comment?

Comment: The guidelines [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/133351) suggest that if one is to strip out the markup of an answer and no useful information remains, then it's a link-only answer. I believe this qualifies.