# StackExchange.Redis.StrongName is refrenced but not included as package

Tags: asp.net-core, stackexchange.redis, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm starting a new project using StackExchange.Redis and .Net Core 2.0.
But I get a conflict:

The type 'ConnectionMultiplexer' exists in both 'StackExchange.Redis.StrongName, Version=1.2.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c219ff1ca8c2ce46' and 'StackExchange.Redis, Version=1.2.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

Why is this showing even thou I'm not referencing StackExchange.Redis.StrongName and it's not even the same assembly version?

Comment: Duplicate question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46029281/vs-net-2017-forces-using-stackexchange-redis-1-2-4-0-in-asp-net-2-0-core-app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added a conditional flag to the "StackExchange.Redis" package, that makes it work. I Tried this solution on two new projects on two machines. Don't ask me why it works tho.

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
      <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
      </PropertyGroup>

      <ItemGroup>
        <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
      </ItemGroup>

      <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0" />
      </ItemGroup> 
      <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.0' ">
        <PackageReference Include="StackExchange.Redis" Version="1.2.6" />
      </ItemGroup>

    </Project>
```

Comment: I cannot get your solution to work. This is my config:
`<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Hangfire.Redis.StackExchange" Version="1.7.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.Web.AspNetCore" Version="4.5.0-rc2" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.0' ">
    <PackageReference Include="StackExchange.Redis" Version="1.2.6" />
  </ItemGroup>`

Any idea?

Comment: Try to move  <PackageReference Include="Hangfire.Redis.StackExchange" Version="1.7.2" /> inside the same ItemGroup as StackExchange.Redis.StrongName, maybe that will work. I haven't worked with Redis anything since this post, so can't swear it will work.

Comment: Did you find any solution to fix the mentioned issues ?

Answer (score 19):

I found my solution [here](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4989).

By adding this (below) to my csproj:

```
<Target Name="ChangeAliasesOfStrongNameAssemblies" BeforeTargets="FindReferenceAssembliesForReferences;ResolveReferences">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ReferencePath Condition="'%(FileName)' == 'StackExchange.Redis.StrongName'">
      <Aliases>signed</Aliases>
    </ReferencePath>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Comment: changing it to 'StackExchange.Redis.' worked for me! I keep coming across this issue. its tiring.

Comment: Nice. Thanks for this. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to use Strongname in your entire application, 1.2.6 is newer and will be used. The problem is when you add Redis.Stackexchange you will have the same namespace from two different dll's. .Net compiler doesn't know which one to use. If you need 1.2.6, use the StrongName version throughout your application and no more problems ....

Comment: This made the headache go away. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis 2.0 that ships with Asp .Net Core 2.0 internally uses StackExchange.Redis.StrongName, Version=1.2.4.0, that there is for example in C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\stackexchange.redis.strongname\1.2.4\lib\netstandard1.5 folder.

So looks it's causes a conflict between different versions of StackExchange.Redis.