# Error with StackExchange.Redis.Extensions and PersistKeysToRedis

Tags: asp.net-core, redis, stackexchange.redis, data-protection

I cannot use both StackExchange.Redis.Extensions and PersistKeysToRedis to services.AddDataProtection

I get error on PersistKeysToRedis:

> `cannot convert from 'StackExchange.Redis.IConnectionMultiplexer' to 'System.Func<StackExchange.Redis.IDatabase>'`

To reproduce the issue:

- Create a WebApp Core 2.2 project
- Install-Package StackExchange.Redis.Extensions.Newtonsoft
- Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Redis -Version 2.2.0-preview2-35157
- Edit .csproj and add this fix https://stackoverflow.com/a/48758961
- Add on ConfigureServices below code

> var redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("Configuration");
>           services.AddDataProtection().PersistKeysToRedis(redis, "RedisKey");

Using

> .PersistKeysToRedis(redis.GetDatabase(), "RedisKey");

always return an error.

So, how I can use PersistKeysToRedis keeping StackExchange.Redis.Extensions (I need it for the StackExchangeRedisCacheClient)